# How do I find the number of occurrences of a substring in a SQL column, as grouped by another column?

Tags: sql, string, group-by, count, pivot

I'm pretty new to SQL, and searched everywhere for an answer to my question but couldn't find one that exactly works.

I have a table with one column of Order IDs, and another with Order notes. I'm trying to find the number of times a word in the Order notes column appears for every ID. So my if my table is something like

```
ORDERID        |   ORDER NOTE
------------------------------------------------
357            |   gardening shoes
213            |   gardening hose
213            |   garden rake
178            |   rake shoes hose
```

I want the below result for searching for instances of "garden" in the database

```
ORDERID        |   COUNT
------------------------------------------------
357            |   1
213            |   2           
178            |   0
```

I can figure out each portion individually, how to group by the ORDERID, and how to get the # of substrings in a table, but can't seem to be able to combine them correctly.

Thanks in advance for the help

Comment: Please tag your question with the database that you are using: mysql, oracle, sql-server...?

Answer (score 1):

You can do conditional aggregation:

```
select orderid, sum(case when order_note like '%garden%' then 1 else 0 end) cnt
from mytable
group by orderid
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=ab2a6aef146a2be9c9ca59d870237808)**:

```
orderid | cnt
------: | --:
    178 |   0
    213 |   2
    357 |   1
```

Note: if you are running MySQL, the conditional sum can be simplified as `sum(order_note like '%garden%')`.